# Using a variable to set a name specific label's visible value to false

Tags: c#, variables, properties, visible, maze

I'm working on a project for an assignment at the moment. I'm in my first year at university and have only just started with c# code, so go easy!

We have to create a game. I chose to design a maze, but want it to be randomised with each play (at least a little). It involves lots of labels arranged in a square to create a maze. Each label has a unique name like MazeWall1Row1, what I would like to do would be to be to feed values into a variable (ideally random numbers) and then use that variable to set the label to visible or not visible.

Say like this:

int iWall = 1, iRow = 1;

MazeWall + iWall + Row + iRow.Visible

And then from that I would randomise the variables iRow and iWall so that I could create a path through the maze.

I've tried looking at other posts like this: http://goo.gl/tRHvVw

But I couldn't get it to work. I would appreciate any help as I think I'll gain a few extra marks by giving the game that little bit more functionality.

Tearing my hair out at this point though!

Comment: In what way do you expect a random *number* to determine a boolean (true or false) value? Sounds like you need to figure out what it's supposed to do before you start trying to program it.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55fb3116-c978-4ac8-9381-a2605e16e256/how-do-you-create-a-random-number-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs

You can use the Random class to create a random number between two specified numbers. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the random numbers to decide which walls should be visible and which shouldn't. You will have to implement the logic yourself, because I don't know what your rules are. :)

Maybe you could do something like if the random number is between x and y, the label should be visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly select one of your controls (that is what I read your question as asking), then you want to do something like this (assuming you are using WinForms):

```
(Controls.Find("MazeWall" + iWall + "Row" + iRow) as Label).Visible = true/false;
```

Basically, you are searching the controls collection for a specific name (generated from your random variables) and setting its Visible property to whatever you want (true/false).

Comment: You may want to look at programmatically creating your controls and storing them in some sort of array, because naming and positioning all those elements in the Designer is going to get old REALLY fast.